# An odd ordered skew symmetric matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ be an odd ordered skew symmetric matrix with all eigen values equal to $0$.

Then how do we show that $M$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb{C}$.

I can see that characteristic polynomial is $x^n$ where $n$ is order of matrix.

For $M$ to be diagonalizable, minimal polynomial must be $x$. So $M$ must be $0$.

But how do we show that $M$ is zero matrix?

Comment: To be clear, is $M$ assumed to have real entries?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $M$ has real entries, set $H=iM$. Then $M$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $H$ is  (obvious).

Denoting $*$ the "bar-transpose" matrix operation, we get  $H^*=i^* M^*=-i M^t=iM=H,$ since $M$ is real skew symmetric. Hence $H$ is a complex hermitian matrix, hence diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. Note that I did not use that $M$ has odd order or has $0$ as a unique eigenvalue to conclude to the diagonalizability.

Note that you can also use the well-known fact that a real skew symmetric matrix is orthonormally similar to a block diagonal matrix, where each block is either $(0)$ or $\pmatrix{0 & b \cr -b & 0}$ for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$., each being diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$...